# Difference between Json getString and toString method can be fatal

Tags: java, json

I am posting this because this subtle difference gave me half day of suffering. Hope this may help others.

The toString method will include the double quote, while the getString method will not.
I am using the latest Java EE Json package from Oracle.

Here is the test code:

```
    JsonArray jarr = Json.createArrayBuilder().add("testString1")
        .add("teststr2").add("Another string").build();

    System.out.println("Testing toString method");
    for (JsonValue jv: jarr) {
        System.out.println(jv.toString());
        System.out.println(((JsonString)jv).getString());
    }
    System.out.println("Testing getString method");
    for (int i=0; i<jarr.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(jarr.getString(i));
    }
```

The print out of the above code:

```
Testing toString method
"testString1"
testString1
"teststr2"
teststr2
"Another string"
Another string
Testing getString method
testString1
teststr2
Another string
```

I was using the string to do look up in a map and I got NULL.  While looking at the string I did not pay attention to the double quote initially.  I was wondering why that I was getting NULL while the key was there for "sure"!

I am not sure this is part of the specification that String Objects are represented by a double quote whereas an unquoted string mean the string itself.

Comment: Not a question. Perhaps you can rephrase it as a question?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `JsonValue.toString()` if the behavior is not desired: this function returns the *[JSON text representation](http://www.json.org/)* of the value (such as `"str"`; all JSON string values are quoted as such), not the *actual content* (such as `str`).

As per the documentation,

> [[JsonValue.toString](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/json/JsonValue.html#toString%28%29)] returns JSON text for this JSON value.

---

The post does *not* demonstrate an issue wrt "NULL" and it is unrelated to `JsonValue.toString()`, when invoked upon an instance. If there is a separate issue, ask a separate question and make sure to include a relevant test-case.