# Android - JSON No value for 1 - but there is using Log

Tags: android, json

I'm stuck at trying to get a simple string from a JsonObject.
Here is the basic code. **result is a JsonObject returned from an Asynctask**. I've done dozens of the same way, and here it doesn't work.

**Response:**{"status":200}

**Error:** An error is thrown saying "**No value for 1**"

When I Log the content of the JsonObject, I get this: 200, which is what I want. For which reason could this return null when there is a value?

**Edit** if I use the result.has("status"); true is returned. I don't understand.

```
    Log.e("TAG", result.get("status").toString());
    try{
        String status = result.getString("status");
    } catch (Exception e){
         e.getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: post your json response

Comment: Please check here the difference b/w toString() and getString() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417947/difference-between-json-getstring-and-tostring-method-can-be-fatal

Comment: post your json response

Comment: Here you go: {"status":200}

Comment: @Isabelle try look my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting int value in the object and you are holding in string which causes the error

You are getting int value in status

```
{ 
 "status":200
}
```

if it is like

```
{ 
 "status":"200"
}
```

Your code works perfectly.

**Try this**

```
    Log.e("TAG", result.get("status").toString());
    try{
        int status = result.getInt("status");
    } catch (Exception e){
         e.getMessage();
    }
```